# services "kubernetes-dashboard" not found when access kubernetes ui

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploy kubernetes UI using this command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

start proxy:

```
kubectl proxy --address='172.19.104.231' --port=8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'
```

access ui:

```
curl http://172.19.104.231:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
http://kubernetes.example.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui/#/dashboard/
```

the log output:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# curl http://172.19.104.231:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 404}
```

how to fix the problem? Check pods status:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# kubectl get pod --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd   0/1     Pending   0          34h
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you use K8S dashboard v2.0.0-betax,

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta8/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Then use this to access the dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

If you use K8S dashboard v1.10.1,

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Then use this to access the dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

I also faced the same problem, but then i realized that dashboard v2.0.0-betax and v1.10.1 use different namespace. Latest version use kubernetes-dashboard namespace, but the older one use kube-system namespace

Answer (score 4):

If you followed instructions from kubernetes.io you might have gotten the wrong link. It's true that service doesn't exist, it might be name that is changed somehow. I had the same issue and noticed that

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

shows (snippet)

```
kubernetes-dashboard   service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.x.y.z    <none>        8000/TCP                 2d14h
kubernetes-dashboard   service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.x.x.y   <none>        443/TCP                  2d14h
```

showed nothing special (as in bored).
Try this link and notice the namespace difference:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/login

That worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This message:

```
"message": "services \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found"
```

Simply means that the service doesn't exist.

First of all check if you'r dashboard (service and pod) are working with this command

```
kubectl get pods,svc --all-namespaces -o wide
```

Please follow the tutorial [Command line proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#command-line-proxy)

About the problem with pod status, please use this command so you will know why the status is pending instead of running.

```
kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-b2lwd -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the error message states for not existing k8s [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in `kube-system` [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) throughout exposed HTTP [API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) proxy method, as @jt97 mentioned in the answer.

For further reference, you might also consider querying K8s inventory objects, once you have [exposed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/http-proxy-access-api/#exploring-the-kubernetes-api) K8s REST API directly within HTTP calls in JSON data format.

For example:

`curl http://172.19.104.231:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/`

Answer (score 1):

try this endpoint:

curl http://172.19.104.231:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

or this one:

curl http://172.19.104.231:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/service/default/kubernetes?namespace=default